# Не отображаются элементы на TabPage в TabControl C#

Tags: c#

Дело в том, что когда я динамически создаю TabControl, а так же 2 TabPage на нем, отображаются элементы только на той TabPage, которая открывается первой (самая левая). Проверяю условие я через конструкцию

```
if (TabControl1.Controls.SelectedTab == TabPage1)
{
  //тут выполняется вывод элементов TabPage1
}
else if (TabControl1.Controls.SelectedTab == TabPage2)
{
  //тут выполняется вывод элементов TabPage2
}
```

Вывод элементов на TabPage у меня идет через функцию, чтобы не загромождать код. Передаю функции только Control с именем TabControl.
Как я понял, программа не может выйти из первого "ифа" (и соответсвенно из первой функции), чтобы отрисовать второй, но может я не прав. Пытался и заранее все отрисовывать, и другие манипуляции делать, но все бестолку. Если кто нибудь приведет пример кода, или хотя бы направит на истинный путь, тому огромная благодарность

Comment: у TabControl есть событие смены вкладок с ним и работай

Comment: то есть ли при смене вкладки у него еще нет детей то вставляем детей иначе не чего

Comment: @Санитариум, я гуглил насчет этой темы, но либо я очень тупой, либо просто не нашел более менее полного ответа. mdsn к сожалению тоже не смог помочь

Comment: Возможно, что вопрос не по делу, но в динамически созданном элементе вы добавили обработчики, откликающиеся на смену вкладки? Как Вам посоветовали выше, Ваш код вывода на страницу должен быть там.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов нет. только через конструкцию if, как я написал в ОП посте. К сожалению, не нашел полной информации, как добавлять обработчик событий на смену вкладки

Comment: "...К сожалению, не нашел полной информации, как добавлять обработчик событий на смену вкладки..." - это первый пункт моего ответа, сделайте так, как там написано.      "... нет. только через конструкцию if, как я написал в ОП посте" - Вашу конструкцию if Вы добавляете в обработчик. Просто тупо реализуйте, то что я написал Вам в ответе и жизнь наладиться :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов если я правильно Вас понял, нужно сделать так, как я сделал. Но тут проблема в том, что я не могу передать обработчику индексы и имена страниц. Вот код примерный (http://prntscr.com/mlgzcy)

Comment: У TabControl есть свойство (property), по моему SelectedIndex, которое содержит индекс выбранной закладки. Анализируйте в своем обработчике его значение. Я внес изменения в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо, возможно Вам это поможет:

1. Там где Вы создаете Ваш `TabControl` Вы должны добавить к нему обработчик, реагирующий на смену закладки, например так:

   ```
    this.tabControl1.TabIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.tabControl1_TabIndexChanged);
   ```
2. Ваш код осуществляющий вывод на страницу Вы помещаете в обработчик:

   ```
   private void tabControl1_TabIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Ваш код, анализирующий страницу и выводящий данные
       if( tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
       {
           //Первая закладка
           //...........
       }
       if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
       {
           //Вторая закладка
           //.............
       }

   }
   ```